# Insecure Content

Tags: html, css, web-deployment, vs-web-site-project

I have a small question. I am building a website from scratch and every time I open it, it does not show all the content. Only text, pictures, and links. I have to go to settings and allow insecure content to somehow "fix" it, but then it says on the address bar "not secure".

Can someone explain this to me and how can I fix this? Thank you for your help.

Comment: ensure everything is served over https.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some content is being served from non HTTPS or sites with a bad cert. Try hosting content on your own server or via some cdn.

Answer (score 0):

check with where your hosting site that it is being served as HTTPS: also can your provide an example of your folder structure your using.